# PageRank algorithm explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently suffering from a case of terrible professor and need someone to explain this algorithm for me. I'll just post a question and would appreciate if someone could walk me through how to solve it.

There are 4 websites A, B, C, D. The webgraph is represented by the following matrix:

```
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

Using d = .2, apply PageRank in the simple form. Show the first three iterations.

I can calculate A using the equation A<sub>ij</sub> = d/n if there is no link from j to i, and A<sub>ij</sub> = d/n + (1-d)/q if there is a link from j to i, where n is the number of pages and q is the number of links on the page j.

However, according to my professor's notes, I'm supposed to revise the vector X, but he never explains what this means. So I guess what I'm looking for is what am I supposed to do after calculating the matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he's referring to the preference vector. With the preference vector you select which nodes will be considered in calculating the centrality of the resulting vector. When you do the scalar product between the preference vector and the resulting matrix you "select" or "weight" how much a node is going to contribute to your final score.
Example: with a uniform vector you simply consider equally the contribution given by all the nodes in the graph.